# Iterate an object to fill the FormData so I can update my Order to Database

Tags: reactjs

So with React I have an normal object where is filled with different kind of data, that I fetch from database, so now after I update the order in the front I want to send the new data object to the Database, and the problem is that I need to send it as Form-data because I have multipy images.

So after I fetch the order I put in on React state and this is how it looks when i console log it:[image: consolelog]:

So now I need to make a formData and fill with all those informations, and send to database, I'm using node for backend thoo.

I've tried this until now:

```
onClick={() => {
  for (let key in data) {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
  }
  dispatch(
    updateOrder({
      token: auth.token,
      id: order.order._id,
      body: formData,
    })
  );
}}
```

But I don't know I'm getting an 500 (Internal Server Error).

Update:

For some reasons the formData is not showing anything when I consoled it.

Here is screenshot of it:
[image: formData]

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` in `onClick`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onClick={() => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    formData.append(key, value);
  }

  dispatch(
    updateOrder({
      token: auth.token,
      id: order.order._id,
      body: formData,
    })
  );
}}
```